# compute age in inner query then comparing with a value

Tags: oracle11g

I have two tables.

1. fbuser(facebook_ID, date_of_birth) - facebook_id is primary key
2. wall(wall_ID, facebook_ID, public_view) - facebook_id is foreign key

I want to find users who have the wall set as public view and whose age is over 24?

```
Select f.facebook_ID from fbuser f, wall w 
WHERE
  (w.public_view='y')
 AND
  (f.facebook_ID=w.facebook_ID)
 AND
  (select FLOOR( MONTHS_BETWEEN( CURRENT_DATE, f.date_of_birth ) / 12 ) 
  as person_age from fbuser where person_age >=24;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  f.facebook_ID
FROM fbuser f, wall w 
WHERE
  (f.facebook_ID=w.facebook_ID)
 AND
  (w.public_view='y')
 AND
  (  (MONTHS_BETWEEN( CURRENT_DATE, f.date_of_birth )/12)  >=24);
```